# Postgres Replication

Tags: postgresql, slony

Is there any technology to replicate a table from public schema on the master server to a table on the slave server but not in the public schema.

```
MASTER SERVER                              SLAVE SERVER
pubic.table_name  ----- replicate ----->   schema1.table_name
```

I tried slony-I but the problem that the table on the slave must in the public schema too.

Comment: Use a foreign data wrapper

Comment: i'm reading about it but i think you gave me what i needed you can put it as an answer and some link for usefull reading.

Answer (score 1):

At least exists three way to do this:

## 1. REPLICATION + VIEW / FDW

You can create *ON MASTER* VIEW or FDW for table and VIEW / FDW will be replicate to slave.

Something like :

```
CREATE VIEW schema1.table_name AS SELECT * FROM public.table_name;
```

Or

```
CREATE SERVER srv FOREIGN DATA WRAPPER postgres_fdw OPTIONS (dbname 'db', host 'localhost');
CREATE USER MAPPING FOR postgres SERVER dc OPTIONS (password 'pwd', "user" 'postgres');
CREATE FOREIGN TABLE schema1.table_name (..table description..) SERVER srv OPTIONS (schema_name 'public', table_name 'table_name');
```

## 2. TRIGGER + SAVE TO REMOTE

You can create trigger on public.table_name on master to write changes to remote db via dblink or FDW.

## 3. LOGICAL REPLICATION

The most hard path as for me. You can write your own decoder and/or add trigger to write also/instead data to schema1.table_name